# Child component not rerendering

Tags: reactjs

I am updating the state of the parent component using setState() and have passed a state parameter to one of the child components but the child component doesn't rerender when the state changes.

Here is my code setup:

1) Parent Component (It calculates the completed tasks(see pt 3) and passes it to the child component)

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            tasks: Tasks,
            completed: 0
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        this.setState((prevState)=>{
            // calculate completed tasks
            prevState.completed = prevState.tasks.reduce((total,curr) => total + (curr.completed?1:0),0);
            return prevState;
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ChildComponent counter={this.state.completed}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

2) Child Component (It displays the count of completed tasks passed from parent)

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            "counter": this.props.counter
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.counter}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

3) Tasks is imported from a file it is something like this:

```
const tasks = [
    {
        id: 1,
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        completed: false
    }
]
```

What happens is the counter stays 0. Why isn't it updating to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try two ways in child component

  1.

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.props.counter}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

or try like

  2.

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            counter: 0
        }
    }
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  if (this.props.counter !== prevProps.counter) {
     this.setState({counter: this.props.counter})
}

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.counter}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why it doesn't work currently? Am new to react and thought I was doing it correctly

Comment: Is only the constructor method called only once and the render method called everytime again ?

Comment: We need to set the state for rerender of component and for the result update.Your approach was just initialising the state in child component but it is not setting it.

Yeah render method will be called every-time when there is a setState and constructor will be called only during initialization 

One more thing you dont need to set the state in child component you can directly pass the props to h1 tag

Comment: I need to update the state bcs I have back and forth data communication. This method doesn't work because componentDidMount() is only called after the first render not after each rerender

Comment: try using a componentdidupdate lifecycle which i have updated in the snippet